# Card does not exist error while posting my details to google now API

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-schemas, google-now

I'm getting **Card does not exist** error while posting my details to google now API can anyone have solution?

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Card 943426934 does not exist."
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Card 943426934 does not exist."
 }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be documentation, but maybe you could try clearing the card from your system and try creating it again.

Comment: @Vignesh Palanichamy : Where did you find Google Now API? There is no documetation right? How are you trying to use it?